# AWS Lambda calling another lambda and then parsing <botocore.response.StreamingBody problem

Tags: python, lambda, aws-lambda, botocore, aws-lambda-layers

The first line is part of response logged after invoking another lambda in 'RequestResponse' type.

```
'StatusCode': 200, 'ExecutedVersion': '$LATEST', 'Payload': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f62887d1410>}
```

The following code is returning null

```
json.loads(lambda_response['Payload'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

The call lambda which is returning response is doing correctly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: @NebiMAydin see my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your lambda can directly call an outgoing internet connection on AWS, then calling another lambda with boto3 works, but if your VPC does not have IG attached, then boto3 calling another lambda doesn't work. If thats the case, make the called lambda an internal private api gateway endpoint and call this endpoint on your calling lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it making sure that the InvocationType is RequestResponse (and not Event, I'm waiting for a response) and then load the response with json.load.

A complete example:

```
response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="WriteToS3",
                                       InvocationType="RequestResponse",
                                       Payload=json.dumps(data))

json_response = json.load(response["Payload"])
print("json.load: ", json_response)
```